# Sort Sql Results By Week Of The Month

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a number of "visits" from many years and we would like to group the results and then get a count by week of the month. How could this best be accomplished by SQL query.

Right now we are doing something like:

```
$query->select(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as `c`, CONCAT(YEAR(created_at), '_', 
WEEKOFYEAR(created_at)) AS `period`"))
->groupBy('period')->orderBy('period');
```

Comment: what is wrong with your current query? can you add some data and explain it better?

Comment: It would be better if you use [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) and create/insert data there and then let us know what you want based on that data.

Comment: There isnt better way to do it. You already using the right way.